# Best primary key for table with changing contents

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I have a 'loan detail' table in SQL Server.

Much like an order/order detail scenario, the detail table has a relationship with a parent 'loan' table, and needs it's own unique primary key because it contains multiple rows per `LoanId`.

However, as it is financial data, it can change on a regular basis — quarterly/6 monthly/annually, rather than daily or hourly.

**I'm trying to establish the primary key for the loan detail table.**

Each loan, may have several loan rates, so I have 2 options in my head at present:

PK1

```
PK: LoanId smallint
PK: AnnualRate decimal(9,4)
```

In this scenario, the annual rate will be used as part of the primary key (since it will be unique for the loan.

The `AnnualRate` column is not connected with any other tables but it will change from time to time.

PK2

```
PK: LoanId smallint
PK: RateId tinyint <-- a surrogate column not used anywhere else
```

Other columns

```
AnnualRate decimal(9,4)
... etc.
```

In this scenario the primary key will not change if a rate changes but rates could still be added or removed by the lender. In short, it will change must less often.

As an inexperienced SQL guy, I'm looking for advice, as any mistake at this point is likely to be difficult to put right further down the line.

Comment: Just use a LoanDetailID column defined as IDENTITY.

Comment: No one can really answer your question intelligently. To do so requires one to understand what your entity actually models. Typically (IME) loans do not have rates that change over time - so your model is unusual. In addition, your choice of name (Details) does not add anything to help understand its purpose. An identity column is likely "good enough", but you should properly constrain the natural key. Unfortunately, that requires a better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a unique identity column as the primary key.  I would expect something along these lines:

```
create table LoanDetail (
    LoanDetailId int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    LoanId int references Loans(LoanId),
    Rate decimal(9, 4),
    eff_date date not null,
    end_date date
);
```

`eff_date` and `end_date` represent the period of time when the rate is effective.

Comment: But the `end_date` can be determined by the `eff_date` of the rate that comes next, no need to add a column.

Comment: @intael . . . The table is much easier to work with if both dates are in each row.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem here is the distinction between a primary key, a natural key, and a surrogate key.

A natural key is a column or group of columns that exist within your data that make the row of data unique. A natural key may or may not exist.

A surrogate key is a column or group of columns that you add to your data to make the row of data unique. You don't 'find' a surrogate key; you built it.

A primary key uniquely identifies a row of data. It may be a natural key or it may be a surrogate key, but in either case it is immutable. Otherwise, you stand to lose referential integrity.

From the sounds of things in your loan details table, the only column that's currently immutable is the LoanId. That's fine, but it means that if you're going to have a primary key on your table, it'll have to be surrogate key, and Gordon has laid out the DDL for setting that up in his answer.

Comment: "A natural key is a... group of columns that exist within your data... A natural key may or may not exist." -- this doesn't make sense to me in context. I have two loans, both with the same institution, and the year they were approved uniquely identifies them to me. The issuer has approved thousands of loans and allocates an account number to uniquely identify each; we call this a trusted source. A natural key with good properties (small, stable, verifiable, familiar to users, maintained by a trusted source, etc) may exist but may be absent from your data e.g. because you didn't do research!

Comment: ...put in the OP's example it seems they need a temporal key i.e. a compound between the load's unique identifier and the time interval during which an interest rate (or whatever) applies, where the open interval further identifies the current interest rate.

Answer (score 0):

In my mind the primary key should be `LoanId` and `DateRateSet` which would be a timestamp that signals when a change in the Rate of a `LoanId` was made. That combination would make `AnnualRate` uniquely identified.

For example:

```
LoanId  DateRateSet          AnnualRate
1       2017-01-01 01:04:20  0.05
1       2017-02-01 01:20:20  0.03
1       2017-08-01 05:04:20  0.05
1       2017-09-01 01:20:24  0.02
```

They could be repeated within the same `LoanId`, but then you will be able to specify a Timestamp for each one.